# Is it possible to store data in solr?

Tags: solr

If I need using small index of few sites, can I store data in solr without using any database?

Comment: are you refering to use Solr for indexing web sites ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use Solr for searching only on few sites.

Comment: You want to index the content of sites through Solr ? and then search with it like google ?

Comment: updated the answer. It is possible and already available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solr probably is not meant to be a DB but as a full text search solution.

It is possible to store data in Solr.
You can mark your fields as [stored=true](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options) and the information would be maintained in Solr.
Solr would store the data on the file system and any issues with the file system or Solr index can lead to loss of data.

The approach mainly followed is to have the Data in DB as a persistent store and have the data indexed in Solr for faster searches.

Edit :-
If you are indexing Web Site data, then you need not store the data in a DB.
[Solr with Nutch Integration](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) can help you achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in Solr, but there are some issues:

- Solr is denormalized as compared to a normal database. Which means no relationships, no foreign keys, no SQL joins
- You have to make sure all the fields are stored, not just indexed
- If you want to display things like HTML straight from Solr, you probably will not be able to use result highlights
- Updating content is somewhat painful, though latest Solr (4+) makes it easier