# Is it possible to store in solr full html page source code?

Tags: java, solr, nutch

In my previous question I got answer that I can store small index (few sites) data in solr without using any data base ([Is it possible to store data in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811669/is-it-posible-store-data-in-solr)). I wonder, if it is possible to store full html page source code in solr without using any data base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nutch with Solr is a solution if you want to Crawl websites and have it indexed.
[Nutch with Solr Tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) will get you started.
However, Nutch would not maintain the Original Solr code with html tags.

You would need to develop an custom solution by downloading the html page and then can use [Solr Extracting Request Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) to feed Solr with the HTML file and extract contents from the html file. e.g. at [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Getting_Started_with_the_Solr_Example)

Solr uses [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to extract contents from the [uploaded html file](http://tika.apache.org/1.2/formats.html#HyperText_Markup_Language)

You can also check [HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) if you are feeding data as html text.

Comment: Can I use nutch for dowloading the html page?

Comment: Nutch is a crawler and it would help you to crawl through the pages and index the content in Solr. However, you wont have the Original content.

Comment: Can I store in index two parts of data (first is content data from nutch and second is original source code from any html parser), how do you think?

Comment: nope .. i dont think you get the Original content from nutch. You may want to check if it is possible.

Comment: May be there is another software solutions which can resolve my task, do you know something about it?